# I change the xib file but the view doesn't update

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xib, tabview

My problem might be simple but i'm not getting the source of it.

An example, i have a tab with 5 views, i change background color to blue of one of those view xibs but went i run the app, the background still white..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Save the xib and then recompile the application.

Comment: @Fábio Martins: I'm not a newbie either, but I still forget one or the other on a regular basis.

Comment: I already resolved my problem, was a error with XCode 4, sometimes it dont connect with Interface Builder.

Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Fábio Martins: Well what a surprise.  Xcode 4 seems still to be a bit flakey still which is why I am still on 3.2.6.  You should perhaps report the bug to Apple,